# Increase timeout for System.Net.Sockets.Socket connect

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, timeout

I need to allow for connections to a FTP server using System.Net.Sockets.Socket to take a long time - at least 30 seconds but possibly more. This code always returns as signalled but not connected after 20 seconds which is apparently the internal default:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect("128.0.0.1", 99, null, null);
bool signalled = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(60000, true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old question, but we had the same problem, so I'll post our solution here.

The WaitOne timeout can be used to force a *lower* timeout than the system default, but if you want to *increase* the timeout (i.e. to more than 20 seconds in your case) you have to change the TCP settings of the underlying operating system.

We ran into this problem on Windows, where we encountered a hard timeout limit on 21 seconds. To change this, you can use the following PowerShell command (running the PowerShell prompt as admin):

```
Set-NetTCPSetting -SettingName InternetCustom -MaxSynRetransmissions 4
```

The default value is 2, which yields an effective TCP connection timeout of about 21 seconds. A value of 3 increases the timeout to about 40 seconds, and 4 to about 90 seconds. More info can be found [here](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/windows-8-10-2012-server-tcpip-tweaks-5077).

For Linux, check out this article:
http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout

Comment: Increasing the system default is not my ideal solution but didn't know it was even possible so I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be what you're looking for:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31514/Implementation-of-Connecting-a-Socket-with-Timeout

It seems that he's using

```
ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()
```

to block the main thread for the duration of the time-out. If

```
IsConnectionSuccessful
```

is false (i.e., the connection was not made in time or the callBack failed) when time runs out, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: It's effectively the same. The AsyncCallback method is executed after 20 seconds which then sets the ManualResetEvent to signalled so the main thread continues and detects that the Socket isn't connected and then throws the exeception.